# How to select rows with a certain number in one of its columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select

In one of the columns of my table (say it's called `foo`), it stores a set of 10 numbers, e.g:

```
1, 5, 8, 3, 4, 6, 9, 7, 12, 15
```

I wish to select all rows of my table which have the number `6` in the `foo` column.

Well, you might say, this sounds simple enough, just do a string search on the column. But the problem is, then you would also select rows with `16` in them, as `16` contains a `6`.

I also thought about searching for `, 6,` instead, but I realized if `6` was on the very end or front of the string, it won't match.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append a `', '` to the beginning and end of `foo` and search:

```
SELECT *
FROM bar
WHERE ', ' + foo + ', ' LIKE '%, 6, %'
```

Comment: I love it when brainy, cheeky solutions are given to a problem hard to solve otherwise (so it seems). lol - will accept when possible.

Answer (score 6):

use MySQL built-in function called `FIND_IN_SET`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('6', REPLACE(foo,' ','')) > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcd64/2)
- [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

From Docs:

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
>   string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
>   string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the
>   first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type
>   SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic.
>   **Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.**
>   Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work
>   properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

Comment: +1 This is the best use of this that I've seen - This function was designed to fit your kind of problem exactly.